# Set buttons display none property by passing button id from Code behind to Jquery Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a code behind function that gives me a button id. Now I want to hide that particular button using jQuery. Here is my code behind

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
    for (int i = 2; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
        int status = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][i].ToString());
        if (status == 1) {
            string columnname = dt.Columns[i].ToString(); //here column name is button id
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "getid", "getid('" + columnname + "');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the jQuery function that I failed to make:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getid(id){
        $(id).toggle('hide');
    } 
});
```

Comment: `toogle` should be `toggle`

Comment: $(id).css('visibility', 'hidden'); even this is not working

Comment: `$(id).css('visibility', 'hidden');` should be `$("#" + id).css('visibility', 'hidden');`

Comment: $("#"+id).hide() or $("#"+id).toggle('hide')

Comment: i hard Coded this   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn1').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }); Even this is not working @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: Your method probably isn't working because the javascript is being rendered in the top of the body tag, before the button is rendered. You'd have to include code to tell the javascript to wait for the DOM to be completely ready to take on your request, which would probably be easiest to do with jQuery.

Comment: Put that in bottom no luck .. but as u said this happens in javascript that why i'm using $(document).ready(function () {}) to check if DOM is  fully loaded

Comment: Can you try a simple 'alert' inside the script and check if that is working?

Comment: alert pops up the message

Comment: Try alerting this and see what you're getting in response: $('#btn1').length.
If you're getting it as '1', it should hide the button. If it is '0', that means the HTML for button has not yet been declared and it's too early for javascript to fire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108175/discussion-between-nishit-vaghela-and-akash).

Answer (score 0):

You might try ensuring that no errors are appearing within the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser (check the Console section).

Additionally, since your function is being defined within your jQuery "document-ready" block, it might not be available whenever your startup scripts are triggering. You could try to resolve this in one of the following ways :

**Try Defining Your Function Outside of the jQuery Section**

```
function getid(id){
    $(id).toggle('hide');
}
```

Additionally, if you didn't want to rely on jQuery at all, you could simply use the following snippet of code :

```
function getid(id){
     var e = document.getElementById(id);
     e.style.display = (e.style.display == "block") ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

**Consider Adding a Delay**

In my experience, I've found that the RegisterStartupScript method can often fire off before what you are calling is actually ready to be called. You can resolve this by adding a slight delay to the call itself using the setTimeout() function :

```
// Set a 10ms delay prior to calling your getid function
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "getid", "setTimeout(function(){ getid('" + columnname + "');},10);", true);
```